# Extract data from gmail into a spreadsheet ignoring the first same field

Tags: parsing, google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail

With this script I am trying to parse the content from my Gmail to Google Spreadsheet and it works well with Google Apps Script.

The problem is that in my mail there are two identical fields called "Indirizzo mail:" that I need to be parsed, but I would to parse only the second.

How could I ignore the first one into the body of the mail?

--- Mail Body Example:

Indirizzo mail: bad@test.it

Phone: 00000000

Website: [www.test.it](http://www.test.it)

---

Lorem Ipsum

Cognome: XXX

Nome: XXX

Codice fiscale: XXX

**Indirizzo mail: good@test.it**

---

```
function parseEmailMessages(start) {

start = start || 0;

var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("testparser");
var threads = label.getThreads();
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {

var tmp,
  message = threads[i].getMessages()[0],
  content = message.getPlainBody();

if (content) {

  tmp = content.match(/Cognome:\s*([A-Za-z0-9!"?`?|õüö’çëÅíšÃÉÁÇÃáéñãóú#&;()-,'@./\s\-]+)(\r?\n)/);
  var Cognome = (tmp && tmp[1]) ? tmp[1].trim() : 'Null';

  tmp = content.match(/Nome:\s*([A-Za-z0-9!"?`?|õüö’çëÅíšÃÉÁÇÃáéñãóú#&;()-,'@./\s\-]+)(\r?\n)/);
  var Nome = (tmp && tmp[1]) ? tmp[1].trim() : 'Null';

  tmp = content.match(/Codice fiscale:\s*([A-Za-z0-9!"?`?|õüö’çëÅíšÃÉÁÇÃáéñãóú#&;()-,'@./\s\-]+)(\r?\n)/);
  var CF = (tmp && tmp[1]) ? tmp[1].trim() : 'Null';

  tmp = content.match(/Indirizzo mail:\s*([A-Za-z0-9!"?`?|õüö’çëÅíšÃÉÁÇÃáéñãóú#&;()-,'@./\s\-]+)(\r?\n)/);
  var Mail = (tmp && tmp[1]) ? tmp[1].trim() : 'Null';

  sheet.appendRow([Cognome,Nome,CF,Mail]);

} // End if

  } // End for loop
}
```

UPDATE:
I have solved to parse all the text except this one:

```
tmp = content.match(/City (Lake's Camil):\s*([A-Za-z0-9!"?`?|õüö’çëÅíšÃÉÁÇÃáéñãóú#&;()-,'@./\s\-]+)(\r?\n)/);
  var ID = (tmp && tmp[1]) ? tmp[1].trim() : 'Null';
```

I suppose not parse and so return null value for round brackets near the word Lake's Camil.
I have tried to insert "\" before "(" but without results.
It is very strange, cause in regex101.com it works.

Comment: What is a field?

Comment: Hello. For field I mean the string in my mail that begins with "Indirizzo mail:"

Comment: Can you provide an email example?

Comment: I have updated the question. As you can see, I would to parse the second string "Indirizzo mail:" and so not the first one.

Answer (score 1):

I'd try something like this:

```
function parseEmailMessages(start = 0) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("testparser");
  const threads = label.getThreads();
  for (let i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    let message = threads[i].getMessages()[0];
    let content = message.getPlainBody();
    if (content) {
      let obj = { pA: [] };
      content.split('\n').filter(l => ~l.indexOf(':')).forEach(l => {
        let lt = l.trim();
        let t = lt.split(':');
        if (t.length == 2) {
          let a = t[0].trim();
          let b = t[1].trim();
          if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(a)) {
            obj[a] = [b];
            obj.pA.push(a);
          } else {
            obj[a].push(b);
          }
        }
      });
      const Cognome = obj['Cognome'];
      const Nome = obj['Nome'];
      const CF = obj['Codice Fiscale']
      const Mail = obj['Indirizzo mail'][1]
      if (Cogname && Nome && CF && Mail) {
        sh.appendRow([Cognome, Nome, CF, Mail]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks, but when I try to run this function, I have this error "SyntaxError: let is disallowed as a lexically bound name line: 8 file No title.gs"

Comment: Are you using the v8 scripting engine?

Comment: I found a typo.

Comment: Yes correct. There was an error in string 7. I have replaced "," with ";" and now works. But when I run the code, nothing happens in the spreadsheet.

Comment: The code will most likely require some debugging.

Comment: And so, how could you suggest me?

Comment: I saw the debug and seems that your code not scan the entire mail. This is a forwarded message mail and so the content I would to parse is in the forwarded messages mail

Comment: I can't predict stuff that you don't provide in the example.

Comment: I have solved with Daniel solution. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

I'm not that great at regex but this should work based on your current code:

```
function parseEmailMessages(start) {

start = start || 0;

var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("testparser");
var threads = label.getThreads();
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {

  var lastposition = threads[0].getId()
  var helper = sheet.getRange("H1") //set the cell where the ID will be stored
   
  if (helper.getValue()==threads[i].getId()){
    helper.setValue(lastposition)  
    break;
  }
  
  if (helper.getValue()==""){// runs only if the helper cell is empty
    helper.setValue(lastposition)
  }

var tmp,
  message = threads[i].getMessages()[0],
  content = message.getPlainBody();

if (content) {

  tmp = content.match(/Cognome:\s*([A-Za-z0-9!"?`?|õüö’çëÅíšÃÉÁÇÃáéñãóú#&;()-,'@./\s\-]+)(\r?\n)/);
  var Cognome = (tmp && tmp[1]) ? tmp[1].trim() : 'Null';

  tmp = content.match(/Nome:\s*([A-Za-z0-9!"?`?|õüö’çëÅíšÃÉÁÇÃáéñãóú#&;()-,'@./\s\-]+)(\r?\n)/);
  var Nome = (tmp && tmp[1]) ? tmp[1].trim() : 'Null';

  tmp = content.match(/Codice fiscale:\s*([A-Za-z0-9!"?`?|õüö’çëÅíšÃÉÁÇÃáéñãóú#&;()-,'@./\s\-]+)(\r?\n)/);
  var CF = (tmp && tmp[1]) ? tmp[1].trim() : 'Null';

  tmp = [...content.matchAll(/(?<=Indirizzo mail: ).*?(?= |\\|\r|\n)/g)];
  var Mail = (tmp && tmp[1][0]) ? tmp[1][0].trim() : 'Null';

  sheet.appendRow([Cognome,Nome,CF,Mail]);

} // End if

  } // End for loop
}
```

**Explanation:** I modified your regex to match all instances of the email and used [`matchAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll) instead of `match()` to get multiple results. This results in a multidimensional array so `tmp[0][1]` holds the "bad" email and `tmp[1][1]` holds the "good" one.

Comment: thanks! It works! But In the sheet after the string "good@test.it" I see also the following row of the body mail. Why?

Comment: I have solved deleting "*" to the last regex

Comment: Glad that it worked, didn’t notice that but I amended my answer with the fix.

Comment: Could I use this code for multiple email with the same label? Cause when I have 2 mails with the same label, return this error: TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined parseEmailMessages @ 2 file senza titolo.gs:27

Comment: I need that the code must work with multiple emails with the same label

Comment: Otherwise i have to parse One mail at a time. And this is not a good solution…

Comment: I have done some test. Now, works! The problem now is only to avoid parsing the same email...

Comment: What do you mean by parsing the same email? The `threads[i]` loop should go over all the threads in the label and it only takes the first message in each thread. Does it repeat somehow?

Comment: Consider that I have multiple threads in the label and considering If now I run the code, it returns some threads. If tomorrow run another time the code, it will return another time the old threads with the new eventual threads and so there will be duplicates for the older. How to avoid this with your code?

Comment: I think there are a few ways that you could do that, one that comes to mind could be to store each [`threads[i].getId()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-thread#getId()) within the loop in a helper cell or a [script property](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/properties), then modify the loop to check the ID of each thread and stop when you find your stored ID. You could also just remove the label after parsing each thread so you won't find it again, or archive them and use `isInInbox()` to check whether or not to parse it again.

Comment: You could also play with read/unread or starred statuses. This could be pretty much another question on its own since there are many ways to handle it depending on your needs, so you may want to post another one if these ideas don't help.

Comment: threads[i].getId() could be a good solution. I could create a column in the sheet to store this ID. But in your code, ho to update it with this add-on?

Comment: I added some code at the start of the `for` loop that works by saving the ID to a cell. Since the newest threads are included at the top you just need to save the first threadId to compare.

Comment: It works but it often happens that when I parse some trhreads, although their structure is the same, I get this error: --- TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined --- What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That would only happen if the `Indirizzo mail` check only returns 1 result instead of 2 (since other undefined values would return `Null` in the sheet). My guess is that the regex does not capture the second email in some of the threads for some reason. Try this regex `/(?<=Indirizzo mail: ).*?(?= |\\|\r|\n)/g`, which I added to the sample. With this one you have to check for `tmp[1][0]` instead.

Comment: I have added your new code for "Indirizzo mail" and now seems to works. However another field despite having a textual content in the body of the email, it returns "null" in the spreadsheet, other times it returns the right value. Am I doing something wrong in the regex?

Comment: Maybe the label of the field I would to parse from the mail contains round brackets @daniel

Comment: I have solved to parse all the text except this one:
tmp = content.match(/City (Lake's Camil):\s*([A-Za-z0-9!"?`?|õüö’çëÅíšÃÉÁÇÃáéñãóú#&;()-,'@./\s\-]+)(\r?\n)/);
  var ID = (tmp && tmp[1]) ? tmp[1].trim() : 'Null';
I suppose not parse and so return null value for round brackets near the word Lake's Camil. I have tried to insert "\" before "(" but without results. It is very strange, cause in regex101.com it works.

Comment: What does the text look like? I tried the regex `/(?<=City \(Lake's Camil\): ).*?(?= |\\|\r|\n)/` and it seems to work for the text `City (Lake's Camil): Example`